# How to get JWT Token from RequestHeader

Tags: java, spring-boot, http-headers

[image]I try to get my bearer token from the header of the getrequest. If I want to display the token, then NULL is returned. Does anyone have any idea why I don't get the token?

```
public String sendSmsToCustomer(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("name") String name,@PathVariable("customer_phone_number") String customer_phone_number, @PathVariable("text") String text) throws Exception
            {
            String user = request.getHeader("Authorization");
            System.out.println(user);
```

**UPDATE 1**

```
public static String getUsernameFromToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        String user = null;
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.

            try {
                user = Jwts.parser()
                        .setSigningKey(SECRET)
                        .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                        .getBody()
                        .getSubject();


            } catch (Exception e) {

                throw e;

            }
            return user;
        }
        else
        return null;
    }
```

**UPDATE 2**

```
        @GetMapping("/contacts/token")
            public String getToken(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception
            {
            String user = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
            System.out.println(user);
            return user;
            }
```

**UPDATE 3**
After I have had the complete header output, I see that "Authorization" is not available.

```
{
    "x-forwarded-host": "localhost:8800",
    "x-forwarded-proto": "http",
    "x-forwarded-prefix": "/contacts",
    "postman-token": "081ea72c-e270-46db-8703-e5afc9887ba1",
    "host": "localhost:8100",
    "x-forwarded-port": "8800",
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "connection": "Keep-Alive",
    "x-forwarded-for": "0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.26.2",
    "accept": "*/*"
}
```

Therefore I will not be able to find the token there either. Is it maybe my dependencies? I only integrated the jjwt dependency for the token. Does anyone have a solution? Been sitting on this bug for several hours

Comment: Can you provide the request sent to the server ? Maybe the token is not in it ? Try with something like Postman, or a junit test, you will be able to reproduce more easily this behavior

Comment: I already work with postman and all requests work, now I want to install a token enhancer and for that I have to get the token

Comment: What do you mean by all requests work ? Can you get the header for other requests except this one ?

Comment: for all other requests i didnt need the token. So they are working an i can go throw the api gateway with the token.

Comment: Have you tried to isolate the problem ? For instance, have you been able to get the token for a method that does not take other parameters ? Maybe you have a security parameter enabled that have a side effect... I've been able to get a token in the header "Authorization" the same way as you did, and it worked well for me. So try to isolate the problem

Comment: i tried to isolate the problem in a separately method. But i still get NULL as response. I  updatet my code

Comment: What I meant was try to "remove" security, making sure there is no side effect. Create a new "Get" method, to avoid any side effects from a previous configuration. Creating a static method is not isolated the problem, as you still have all your configurations applied, and potentially a lot of side effect

Comment: in Update 2 i wrote a new get method to get my token. But still get NULL as response

Answer (score 1):

You should provide us the request you are sending to check if the token was send.
Maybe you can also try receiving it like this by adding this header

```
@RequestHeader("Authorization") String token
```

Comment: i tried this way too, but the method getHeader didnt work after that

Comment: i changed it now i got this error 2020-07-27 09:44:54.805  WARN 13012 --- [nio-8100-exec-1] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.bind.MissingRequestHeaderException: Missing request header 'Authorization' for method parameter of type String]

Comment: Okay, so you are not sending the token with the header's name Authorization, check again your request. In postman, are you sending the token in the tab "Authorization" with the type "Bearer Token" ?

Comment: Yes i am sending with Bearer Token. I updated a picture with my postman get request

Comment: I don't know if it's because you send it in the header panel, but try sending the token in the Authorization panel with "Bearer token option"

Comment: Spring Boot applies a filter chain to incoming requests, and one of the first of these is security. So by the time your application gets control, the information you want may have been removed from the request headers and placed in the security context. So you'll need to obtain it from there instead.

Answer (score 0):

If `request` is the Request object, then you can do:

```
request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION);
```